# Connection dropped detection

Tags: go, http2

I do run an internal tunnel service in our network based on `http2.ServeConn`. This call should block until the connection is not readable anymore.

```
c.httpServer.ServeConn(conn, &http2.ServeConnOpts{
    Handler: http.HandlerFunc(c.serveHTTP),
})
```

That works perfectly when I kill the other end (in this case the tunnel server). However if the connection is killed by a firewall (for instance if it is configured to drop connections on idle) then I do not get any notification here and the connection remains open, but unusable.

Is there an option to detect that? Or does anybody had such an issue? The source of the tunnel is available [here](https://github.com/hons82/go-http-tunnel) in case somebody wants to check.

Comment: Did you configured a `--state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` rule in iptables ?